Optimizing Model Parameters Issue with 'loss.backward()' Function
import gc

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False)


gradient_norms = []

losses = []

for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):

    model_path = f"/kaggle/working/Training/ace_state_dict_{epoch+1}.pth"

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path)

    model.train()

    total_loss = 0

    
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader, desc=f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}')):

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        logits = model(batch["inputs"])

        targets = batch["targets"]

        loss = loss_fn(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), targets.float()) / 1000000000

        loss.backward()        

        # Compute gradient norms

        grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1)

        gradient_norms.append(grad_norm)

        optimizer.step()

        scheduler.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()
        

        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:

            print(f'Batch {batch_idx}/{len(train_dataloader)}, Loss: {total_loss/(batch_idx+1)}, Gradient Norms: {grad_norm}')

    
    avg_loss = total_loss / len(train_dataloader)

    losses.append(avg_loss)

    print(f"Train loss: {avg_loss}")`

In my code above, the loss.backward() function is not working as expected, resulting in a grad_norm consistently registering as 0.0. This impedes the optimization of the model's parameters during each iteration. Any guidance or suggestions to rectify this matter? For reference, you can find the full source code of my model at:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/cutedeadu943/transformerchatbot
I've experimented with various combinations of hyperparameters and learning rates, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Additionally, I attempted to address it by employing torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(), but to no avail. All the relevant tensors and the model's parameters are set with requires_grad=True. Any insights or alternative approaches to resolve this?
